# Pictures gone after Nandroid backup restored

Tags: backup, nandroid

Recently, I made a TWRP Recovery Nandroid backup of my current ROM, and I had just taken some personal pictures. In the backup, it included the /data partition. When I went to restore it, I opened the Photos app, and nothing was there. I checked the file system, and the camera and DCIM folders are empty. Is there any way to get the pictures back?

I am on HTC One M8 GPe Android 5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the way nandroid works. Its **NOT** some bug.

Yes, it does include `/data` partition but your data is stored in `/data/media/0` which it skips during backup as this would lead it to backup *everything* inside internal memory increasing backup size significantly.

In other simple words, nandroid backup's `/data` option includes only apps and their data, not your personal data on internal or external sd.

As for restore, there are a bunch of apps that claim to be able to recover deleted/formatted data such as [Undelete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete) (you need to be Rooted for this one) but I have never personally tried one so can't say about the performance. So you will have to test those yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, though I doubt Undelete would work, as I flashed a ROM and a kernel over after the initial backup.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected... I tried out the app, it got everything back for me, even found pictures from weeks ago... The even more amazing thing is, I flashed at least 5 different ROMS and did factory resets.

Comment: So basically Nandroid doesn't back up your media and personal data to decrease backup size significantly? That makes no sense. Why even bother to do a backup? In that case I can reduce the backup size to 0 and just not do anything.

Comment: I would have expected a Nandroid being a complete backup. Originally, it was even a partition dump. Have you any backing for that? // `/data/media/0` corresponds to the "internal SD card", so it *somehow* even makes sense (Nandroid doesn't backup the external card either). So one must be aware to backup SD cards separately it seems?